# How to enter the values in database?

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

```
import easygui as eg
import sqlite3``        

conn = sqlite3.connect('ATM.sqlite')
        print("Connected to database successfully")
        conn.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists CUSTOMER(ID INTEGER, Name TEXT, Address TEXT, Mobile_no INTEGER, PIN INTEGER, Balance INTEGER)")

    def Admin_AddUser():
        options = ['ID', 'Name', 'Address', 'Mobile No.', 'PIN']
        Current_bal = 0
        value = eg.multenterbox('Enter the information for new user', 'Add User', options)
        conn.execute('INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (ID, Name, Address, Mobile_no, PIN, Balance) VALUES'
                     '( value[0],value[1],value[2],value[3],value[4],int(Current_bal))')
```

I wish to enter the details in the customer table. But it is showing me the following error.

```
    sqlite3.OperationalError: near "[0]": syntax error
```

Comment: Did you find your solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
data =  [value[0],value[1],value[2],value[3],value[4],int(Current_bal)]

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (ID, Name, Address, Mobile_no, PIN, Balance) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?)', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters:

```
conn.execute('INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (ID, Name, Address, Mobile_no, PIN, Balance) 
              VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)',
             [value[0],value[1],value[2],value[3],value[4],int(Current_bal)])
```